# How to center text in VB.net? (Console)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I want to print text "TEST" (Console.WriteLine) in the center of my VB.net console application. How would I go about doing so?

Looking for 'beginner-friendly' answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to get the [console with](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.windowwidth%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), get the [length of the string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.length.aspx) you're about to display and, subtract the second from the first, divide this in half and pad the string with this number of spaces.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim text As String : text = "[Insert Text Here]" : Console.WriteLine(text.PadLeft((Console.WindowWidth / 2) + (text.Length / 2)))
```